# Is there a way to make Webpack 2 ignore require (CommonJS) calls? To not transpile them?

Tags: javascript, webpack, requirejs, commonjs

I have code that has

```
require(...)
```

can we make Webpack ignore that and not touch it, so that I can use runtime RequireJS from my Webpack bundle?

The reason is because I'd like to have new code in my app compiled with webpack, and allow it to use RequireJS to pull my old code which is already requirejs calls with a bunch of hacks that are way to difficult to port to modern modules. I just want to import them the old way while write new code with Webpack.

How can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

Put your new code inside a folder, and point a webpack to it, or the opposite, put your legacy code in a folder, or rename each legacy file as file.legacy.js and then use Ignore Plugin:

```
var ignore = new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/legacy.js$/)

module.exports = {
  //other options goes here
  plugins: [ignore]
}
```

Comment: I know this makes webpack ignore those files, but does this make Webpack ignore the `require('path/to/legacy.js')` calls and NOT transpile those calls so that they remain intact in the final bundle?

Comment: @trusktr yes. they will remain intact

Comment: Sweeet, I'll take your word for it. Ends up my requirements changed so I won't end up trying it, for now.

Comment: oh, but, what about just ignoring ALL require calls, regardless of which file is required?